# Multiple instance model in Keras

Tags: machine-learning, keras, classification

I have a multiple instance dataset for which I want to predict the instance category as well as a (derived) bag label using Keras' Functional API. Simple instance prediction works and getting a bag label from that also works. But since the bag label is outside of the model the results seem to be suboptimal.

My thinking is as follows:

1. For each instance in a bag, start up a separate branch of the model.
2. After running each instance through its branch, concatenate the results.
3. After concatenation, predict the bag label based on probabilities

What I have written so far - here, `n_instances` is the number of instances per bag, `n_feat` the number of features per instance, and `n_classes` the number of possible categories an instance/bag can belong to.

```
from keras.layers import *

inputs = []
instance_layer = [None] * n_instances

for i in range(n_instances):
    inp = Input(shape=n_feat)
    inputs.append(inp)
    instance_layer[i] = Dense(units=256, activation='ReLU')(inp)
    instance_layer[i] = Dense(units=128, activation='ReLU')(instance_layer[i])
    instance_layer[i] = Dense(units=64, activation='ReLU')(instance_layer[i])
    instance_layer[i] = Dense(units=n_classes + 1, activation='sigmoid')(instance_layer[i])  # output to be converted to one-hot vector

output_tensor = Concatenate()(instance_layer)

"""
Code to go from concatenated tensor to a single bag prediction
"""

model = tf.keras.models.Model(inputs, output_tensor)
```

Issues:

- It seems to me like each instance sees a separate model while I want to keep the models identical
- Concatenate() produces a tensor of length n_instances*n_classes, whereas I'm interested in a tensor of shape (n_instances, n_classes). I would prefer to use CategoricalCrossEntropy as a loss function.
- Any pointers on how to go from this tensor of instance predictions to a bag prediction?

Answer (score 0):

For posterity:

```
instance_model = tf.keras.models.Sequential([
    Dense(units=256, name='fc_256', activation='ReLU', input_dim=n_feat),
    Dense(units=128, name='fc_128', activation='ReLU'),
    Dense(units=64, name='fc_64', activation='ReLU'),
    Dense(units=n_classes+1, name='label_predictions', activation='sigmoid')
])
```

This is then wrapped in a TimeDistributed layer which returns a tensor with *n_instances* rows and *n_classes+1* columns, for an input tensor of *n_instances* rows and *n_feat* columns. *n_instances* is variable here, hence the None in the input shape:

```
inputs = Input(shape=(None, n_feat), name="input")
instance_output = TimeDistributed(instance_model)(inputs)

# Condense into bag prediction
bag_output = GlobalAveragePooling1D(name="pooling")(instance_output)

model = tf.keras.models.Model(inputs, bag_output)
```